# PHP fopen forloops

Tags: php

I'm not exactly sure why this isn't working I tried googling it to see if there was a answer a lot of them came up with a foreachloop instead of regular for loops can someone explain to me why this isn't working.

```
<?php
$list = array("GOOG", "AAP", "MSFT");

    for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
    {
        echo "why isn't this working <br>";

        $fp = fopen ("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=sl1ve1x&e=.csv","r");
        $data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ",");
        $exit = str_replace('"',"",$data[3]);
        $exchange = str_replace('"',"",$data[4]);

        echo "$data[0] <br>";
        echo "$data[1] <br>";
        echo "$data[2] <br>";

    }
?>
```

I expected it to print google info 3 times it doesn't if I take fopen out by itself once it works but if I do it multiple times it just doesn't do anything what I expected is

output ex

```
why isn't this work
Goog
8398
789
why isn't this work
Goog
8398
789
why isn't this work
Goog
8398
789
```

Comment: "Breaks" how? Do you get errors? What is the expected output exactly and what do you get instead?

Comment: It just doesn't work at all I expected like 3 repeated echo of google information but it doesn't even echo anything.

Comment: Why do you reopen the same file in loop? Why don't you close them? Also enable error reporting to see what errors/warnings/notifications.

Comment: Works on my m/c. btw, do a `fclose` as well.

Comment: Okay apparently my php server was messing with me and turn itself off and was the reason why it wasn't working...I hate my idiocy sometimes.

Comment: If your server was `turning itself off`, you would have got a whole bunch of other errors entirely unrelated to this script.

Comment: now that you mention it... looking into it further the error seems to be trickling up my javascript guess ill dig further down

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a foreach?

```
<?php
$lists = array("GOOG", "AAP", "MSFT");

foreach($lists as $list)
{
    echo "<h3>Values for ".$list."</h3>";

    $fp = fopen ("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$list."&f=sl1ve1x&e=.csv","r");
    $data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ",");
    fclose($fp);

    echo $data[0]."<br/>",
         $data[1]."<br/>",
         $data[2]."<br/>";
}
/* Result
Values for GOOG
GOOG
681.72
1582936
Values for AAP
AAP
80.44
1306227
Values for MSFT
MSFT
29.86
43408272
*/
?>
```

### Edit:

You may also be interested to know that by looping with fopen is roughly 4.6 times slower then using curl_multi as curl multi will make all the requests simultaneously, here are the results:

Simple curl multi function:

```
<?php
function curl_multi_get($data) {
    $curly = array();
    $result = array();

    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    foreach ($data as $id=>$d) {
        $curly[$id] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s='.$d.'&f=sl1ve1x&e=.csv');
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        30);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    true);
        curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
    }
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while($running > 0);
    foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
        $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Did Curl multi in **0.50315880775452** seconds

```
<?php
//Benchmark test 1 curl_multi
$time_start = microtime(true);
//---------------------------------------

$lists  = array("GOOG", "AAP", "MSFT");
$result = curl_multi_get($lists);

foreach($result as $data)
{
    $data = explode(',',$data);

    echo "<h3>Values for ".$data[0]."</h3>";

    echo $data[0]."<br/>",
         $data[1]."<br/>",
         $data[2]."<br/>";
}

//--------------------------------------
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did Curl multi in $time seconds\n";
//end first test
//Did Curl multi in 0.50315880775452 seconds
?>
```

Did fopen() in **2.3253791332245** seconds

```
<?php
//Benchmark test 2 fopen()
$time_start = microtime(true);
//--------------------------------------

$lists = array("GOOG", "AAP", "MSFT");
foreach($lists as $list)
{
    echo "<h3>Values for ".$list."</h3>";

    $fp = fopen ("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=".$list."&f=sl1ve1x&e=.csv","r");
    $data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ",");
    fclose($fp);

    echo $data[0]."<br/>",
         $data[1]."<br/>",
         $data[2]."<br/>";
}

//--------------------------------------
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did fopen() in $time seconds\n";
//end second test
//Did fopen() in 2.3253791332245 seconds 
?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the better syntax I never really looked into this type of loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lists  = array("GOOG", "AAP", "MSFT");
$result = curl_multi_get($lists);

foreach($result as $data)
{
    $data = explode(',',$data);

    echo "<h3>Values for ".$data[0]."</h3>";

    echo $data[0]."<brtextmessagedfghjkljhgfdsadfghjkkjhgfdsasdfghjklkjhgfdsasdfghjkkjhgfdsasdfghjkjhgfdsdfghjkkjhgfdsdfghjm,.,mnbvcxsdfghjklkjhgfdsdfghjkllkjhgfdsa/>",
         $data[1]."<br/>",
         $data[2]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: what will u do if u want to change some data

Comment: Is that a question or an answer?